# Error “fail cache” on web server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have a production web server with Plesk 12 running on Debian. A website is running with Laravel 4.2, but I think that error is not Laravel problem. I think is problem with Apache/Nginx (Plesk have nginx to cache static files).

The error show a blank page with the message "fail cache" it's totally random, we can't reproduce that error, because we do the same some times and probably no occurred and sometimes yes.

Log

```
[Wed Jul 15 04:56:19 2015] [error] [client 1] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/web_users 
[Wed Jul 15 04:56:31 2015] [error] [client 1] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/web_users 
[Wed Jul 15 04:56:41 2015] [error] [client 1] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/web_users 
[Wed Jul 15 08:28:43 2015] [error] [client 2] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/public/uploads/posts/, referer: http://www.web_host.com/admin/posts 
[Wed Jul 15 08:28:47 2015] [error] [client 2] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/public/uploads/posts/, referer: http://www.web_host.com/admin/posts 
[Wed Jul 15 10:46:53 2015] [error] [client 3] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/web_users 
[Fri Jul 17 08:33:03 2015] [error] [client 4] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/web_host.com/public/tmp/posts/files/
```

I search in google, in this website, but nothing found, any one can help my to solve this problem? How can I do? Where can I start to search?

Comment: I am not familiar with plesk but can you attach the apache/nginx logs for the occurences of the error? That might help a lot in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @Richard add log of the one day my client send my that error appear in web.

Comment: Grep your application code for "fail cache" and try find out why this code is triggering. Or post code snippet here.